# Left to Right and Right to Left Animation from Android 2.1 and above

Tags: android, android-animation

Transitive animation on android 2.1 to 4.2 is very weird in android. The code below found in my anim folder works well on android 4.0 and above version. i have not tested it with version 3. But my minimum sdk version is 2.1, these animation does not work on it.  Is there an issue on implementing animation on android compatible with version 2.1 to 2.3 or should i implement my animation programatically. My aim is to switch activity from left to right and right to left.

**anim/anim_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="50%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

**anim/anim_right.xml**

Comment: post more code of how are you using this animations.

Comment: `But my minimum sdk version is 2.1, these animation does not work on it.` What is the problem in 2.1 sdk ? There should not be any effect on animations with 2.1 or 4.0 AFAIK.

Comment: Below my intent activity i use overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_left, R.anim.anim_right);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this programatically: for example:

```
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -1*screenHeight(this));   
             slide.setDuration(1000);

                // slide.setFillAfter(true);   
                chargement_rel.startAnimation(slide); 
                slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, screenHeight(this), 0);   
                slide.setDuration(1000);   
               // slide.setFillAfter(true);   
                chargement_rel.startAnimation(slide);
```

Comment: this one works for bottom to top,can you put for left to right and right to left

Comment: can you help me with top to bottom animation

Comment: thank you so much @Nikita,just what i wanted ..
worked like a charm :)